# jquery replace string from string using regular expression

Tags: jquery, regex

from XML string I want to remove

```
]]><![CDATA[
```

i tried in following way :

```
var find = "]]><![CDATA[";
var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
xmldata = xmldata.replace(re, '');
```

its giving error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //]]>

what is the issue ?

Comment: "]]><![CDATA[" that's not a regular expresion, use the standar replace instead. [ xmldata = xmldata.replace(find, ''); ]

Comment: @frikinside will it replace all such string ?

Comment: Sadly... don't. This it will only replace the first ocurrence. If you need to replace all concurrences you'd be forced to use RegExp. In that case, go for @CasimitEtHippolyte way. I usually create a ` replaceAll` function when loop the replace until no ocurrences left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must escape the opening square brackets:

```
]]><!\\[CDATA\\[
```

Comment: @Chintan_chiku: thanks, however frikinside's alternative seems to be the best way for your specific case.